# Elasticsearch searching for the exact query with space

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, elastica

i want my search return the exact match of my query string.
Query String includes 2 words.

query :"general doctor" should  return only general doctor not "doctor general"

Search method:

```
$lower = 'general doctor';

$query = new \Elastica\Query\MatchAll();

$tagquery = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
$tagquery->setDefaultField('branchslug');
$tagquery->setFieldBoost('branchslug', 10);
$tagquery->setQuery(mb_strtolower($lower, 'UTF-8'));

$tagfilter = new \Elastica\Filter\Nested();
$tagfilter->setPath('expertdetailbranchid');
$tagfilter->setQuery($tagquery);
$tagfilter->setCached();


$filterBoolArticle = new \Elastica\Filter\Bool();
$filterBoolArticle->addMust($tagfilter);
$filterBoolArticle->setCached();
```

index mapping: http://pastebin.com/JJkc9jq4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved problem.

```
$lower = '"general doctor"';
```

instead of

```
$lower = 'general doctor';
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you answered your own question, but this may be of use...

**Lucene Query Syntax**
http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html